# C# Entity Framework 6: Automatically register custom type converters

Tags: c#, entity-framework

We have a application where we use EF6 and code first with the sql-ce backend.

We have several classes which have properties that cannot be automatically mapped/converted by Entity Framework (= those properties will not be saved to and loaded from database). For instance:

```
public class FavShowData {
   //....

   public ObservableCollection<String> Categories { get; set; }

   //...
}
```

In order to save this property anyway, we often introduce another member:

```
public string CatString {
    get
    {
        return String.Join("\n", Categories);
    }
    set
    {
        Categories.Clear();

        foreach (string cat in value.Split('\n'))
        {
            Categories.Add(cat);
        }
    }
}
```

This works nice, but also generates a lot of duplicate code (for every single property which cannot be mapped).

I would like to define in my CustomDBContext the custom conversion for type X, and then that conversion should be used to all Properties of PropertyType X.

I started with the following code:

```
 public class CustomDbContext : DbContext
 {
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
             modelBuilder.Properties().Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(ObservableCollection<String>)).Configure(
                delegate(ConventionPrimitivePropertyConfiguration configuration)
                {
                    //register custom converter somehow ..
                });

        }

    //...
    public DbSet<FavShowData> FavShowData { get; set; }

}
```

First of all my deleagte is never called. And even if it would: How would I register a custom type converter?

Comment: Is That all your entities have same name for ObservableCollection<String> property ?

Comment: @CodeNotFound : Nope. And also: Finding the property is not the problem. Configuring the property is the problem. See also this gist: https://gist.github.com/Dreamcooled/7264611e9fea1908ecbb

Comment: There is no type convereter or such with EF. You can just override the SaveChanges methods then attempt to do the thing you are doing on the OnModelCreating method.

Comment: @CodeNotFound: But then I would need to manually track the changes of the properties in question, and manually save/restore them from db, right?

Comment: save indeed.Restoring, EF will do thatg for you.

Comment: How can EF restore a property which it doesn't track, nor does know a mapping for it?

Comment: You override then OnMaterialized method

Comment: The feature you're looking for is a long-standing EntityFramework feature request: https://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions/suggestions/2639292-simple-type-mapping-or-mapped-type-conversion-supp. It's the third most popular feature request at the moment, but the EF team still hasn't begun addressing it. If you have votes to spare, please consider using them for this.

Comment: @devuxer: thanks for that link. 3 votes added :)

Answer (score 1):

This is now possible in EF Core 7 with [ValueConversions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions?tabs=data-annotations#bulk-configuring-a-value-converter)

By making your own type for the values that need special treatment

```
public class CatString : ObservableCollection<string>
{
}
```

Using that class in your entity models instead

```
public class FavShowData {
   //....

   public CatString Categories { get; set; }

   //...
}
```

and then creating a ValueConverter class for your type

```
 public class CatStringConverter : ValueConverter<CatString, string>
 {
     public CurrencyConverter()
         : base(
             v => String.Join("\n", v),
             v => {
                 var categories = new CatString();
                 foreach (string cat in value.Split('\n'))
                 {
                     categories.Add(cat);
                 }
                 return categories;
             })
     {
     }
 }
```

And then overriding ConfigureConventions in your

```
 protected override void ConfigureConventions(ModelConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder)
 {
     configurationBuilder
         .Properties<CatString>()
         .HaveConversion<CatStringConverter>();
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're only doing this for `ObservableCollection<T>` objects (or better yet, `<string>`, why not just inherit from that class and provide a new method?:

```
public class MyObservableCollection<T>
    : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    public string GetCollectionString()
    {
        return string.Join("\n", this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: This question is about Entity Framework!
I need entity framework to save my Categories Property to Database, and for that I need a registered converter. Subclassing observable collection has not the desired effect.